# A non-null String must be proided to a text widget

Tags: flutter

```
List<Question> questionBank =[
    Question(b: 'You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.', a: true) ,
    Question(b: 'Approximately one quarter of human bones are in the feet.',a: false),
    Question(b: 'A slug\'s blood is green.',a: false),
  ];
  int questionNum=0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
               questionBank[questionNum].questionText,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

I try to get Text from class 'Question' and, I use 'questionNum' like an index. 
I had try to `Text(questionBamk[questionnum].questionText??'default value` it show 'default value'.
this is the class code I have been use it

```
class Question {
  String questionText ;
  bool questionAnwsear;
  Question ({String b ,bool a}){
    b= questionText ;
    a= questionAnwsear;
  }
}
```

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu can you help me ?

Comment: @AdilSakout check out my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
questionBank[questionNum].questionText!=null?questionBank[questionNum].questionText : 'loading ...'


//change your class like this,
class Question {
  String questionText ;
  bool questionAnwsear;
  Question({this.questionText ,this.questionAnwsear});
}

//then call like 

Question(questionText: 'You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.', questionAnwsear : true);
```

Comment: no error now but it Show 'loading ... ' ,  I need to get the string from class

Comment: do you know what is `??` operator?

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu yes I am acquainted with null aware operators very well, you shoud know not using is not always not knowing, but thanks for asking.

Comment: not so well obviously if you write something like `questionBank[questionNum].questionText!=null?questionBank[questionNum].questionText : 'loading ...'` instead simply `questionBank[questionNum].questionText ?? 'loading ...'`

Comment: ?? Assign the value only if the variable is null, but the class in not empty

Comment: @AdilSakout I am glad its working, you can accept my answer. thanks.